# @grpc/grpc-js doesn't install all dependencies

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, grpc-js

I have just added @grpc/grpc-js with `npm i @grpc/grpc-js` into my project. When I try to use it, I get no compile time errors. However, I get runtime errors like this:

```
./node_modules/.pnpm/@grpc+grpc-js@1.8.12/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/channel-credentials.js:20:0
Module not found: Can't resolve 'tls'

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/.pnpm/@grpc+grpc-js@1.8.12/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/index.js
./pages/proto/index.tsx

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
```

tls isn't the only one, http2, net, dns, fs, and others are also not found. I don't know why, I don't know how to fix this other than using `npm i <missing module>`  but this seems ridiculous. I can't find any information about these errors, and I wonder if I'm doing something wrong? Can someone help me out with this?

Answer (score 1):

`@grpc/grpc-js` is only for Node. It looks like you are attempting to use it inside of a front-end web app (i.e. running in a browser), which is not supported. `tls` is an internal Node package.

Comment: I'm confused about what you mean. I'm using NextJS and node. What is the difference, and where in my code can I/can I not use @grpc/grpc-js?

Comment: the `index.tsx` must be being built with the web browser in mind. I would read the next.js docs to find out how to have a pure server side dependency. you can't use `@grpc/grpc-js` in a web browser

Comment: Ok so I can use @grpc/grpc-js server side but not client side?

Comment: correct. that is what I said.